# Can I create/learn ASP.NET apps for free?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I have just downloaded Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition(I heard that 2008 is better as far as performance goes), but there is no ASP.NET. Is it available in 2010 Express Edition or do I need some 30-day trial edition(or buy VS)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want [Web Developer](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/), also part of the Express suite. Also, I'm pretty sure Web Developer works fine with MVC - you *might* want to look at the MVC over web-forms, but both technologies have supporters (bother are ASP.NET; a lot of old texts incorrectly confuses "ASP.NET" and "webforms"; ASP.NET is the *platform* - webforms / MVC are specific methodologies *within* the platform).

Comment: I thought nowadays it's all about [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix)?

Comment: You can use either depending on what you are looking for. Visual Web Developer definitely works fine with ASP.NET MVC. There is no built in test project support in Visual Web Developer (but you can use XUnit, NUnit etc) which is probably the major difference from Visual Studio that you would notice if you are working on ASP.NET MVC projects.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get up and running with web development on the Microsoft web stack is to use the Web Platform Installer: http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

With that, you can freely download both IDEs (e.g. Visual Studio 2010 Express and WebMatrix) and frameworks (e.g. .NET 4.0 and ASP.NET MVC 3).

Unless you have a very slow machine, definitely go for Visual Studio 2010.  It's quite a bit better than 2008 - especially for web development.